# Oracle Statement to sum a calculated column by another column

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to add all the extended prices for a company. 
Instead of my results being

```
Company_1 2000
Company_1 2000
Company_1 1000
Company_2 2000
Company_2 1000
```

I would like to see

```
Company_1 5000
Company_2 3000
```

here is my current statement.

```
SELECT COMPANIES.COMPANY_NAME, 
       INVC_HEADER.INVOICE_DATE, 
       (INVC_DETAIL.QTY_SHIP * INVC_DETAIL.UNIT_PRICE) as Ext_Price
  FROM ( INVC_DETAIL INVC_DETAIL 
 INNER JOIN INVC_HEADER INVC_HEADER 
    ON INVC_DETAIL.INH_AUTO_KEY = INVC_HEADER.INH_AUTO_KEY ) 
 INNER JOIN COMPANIES COMPANIES 
    ON INVC_HEADER.CMP_AUTO_KEY=COMPANIES.CMP_AUTO_KEY
 ORDER BY COMPANIES.COMPANY_NAME, INVC_HEADER.INVOICE_DATE DESC
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a `SUM` of the value you are looking for and `GROUP BY` Company Name

```
SELECT COMPANIES.COMPANY_NAME, 
        SUM(INVC_DETAIL.QTY_SHIP * INVC_DETAIL.UNIT_PRICE) as SumExt_Price
FROM   (INVC_DETAIL INVC_DETAIL INNER JOIN INVC_HEADER INVC_HEADER ON INVC_DETAIL.INH_AUTO_KEY=INVC_HEADER.INH_AUTO_KEY) 
        INNER JOIN COMPANIES COMPANIES ON INVC_HEADER.CMP_AUTO_KEY=COMPANIES.CMP_AUTO_KEY
GROUP BY COMPANIES.COMPANY_NAME
```